mdb database not working after upgrade from Win 7 to Win 10
I've today upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10.
I've installed IIS (10) and moved the various sites into the the default folder (wwwroot)
Typing 'http://localhost/warweb/' in the browser opens the brings up the default.asp page, but it crashes when attempting to open the mdb database.
The code I've been using for years with Windows 7 is as below.
Set adoCon2 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
adoCon2.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("data/cwardead.mdb")
Set rswardead2 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Do I need to upgrade this for IIS 10?
It's about ten years since I last set up an IIS server for local use.
I sorta hoped it would work straight off, without tweaking the code.

Does your IIS run as a 32 or 64 bit process?

Probably you got an error message that explains the reason for the crash Care to share it with us?

As suggested, force the project when building to x32, you can't use ANY cpu. And also, in IIS, it also defaults to x64 bits, but Access mdb files and JET are x32 bit programs. So, once again, enable x32 bit processes in IIS.

Many thanks HansUp and Albert. Enabling 32-bit solved the problem.
I had no idea that mdbs are 32-bit only. There's a load more questions to be asked on this, but that's for another day.
Again, many thinks.

mdb don't care about x32 or x64, but the database engine JET you are using is what matters, and there is only a x32 bit version of JET. There is a x64 bit version of ACE, and in most cases, it can open a mdb file - but it will depend on how old the mdb file is.

You probably followed articles like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/using-classic-asp-with-microsoft-access-databases-on-iis to configure your IIS 7 machine decades ago to run properly but forgot the same changes are required on IIS 10.

@AlbertD.Kallal  mdb is the file extension which is (conventionally) assigned to a JET database.  ACE databases are assigned the extension accdb.  The Microsoft Access programme can open and edit both formats,  JET is 32 bit only, ACE is 64 bit only.  ODBC and OLEDB drivers for JET ship with Windows but you have to download and install the drivers for ACE.  (If you install Access they're bundled with it).

Thanks John,  quite much what I stated in my 2 comments.  ACE can open most mdb files (2000-2003), but access 97 often requires JET.
